# Unable to Boot Live CD to resize disk partition

Tags: 11.10, boot, virtualization, gparted

I have a working version of 11.10 installed on VMware but I need to increase my disk space.

I tried to boot from iso (on windows drive), but neither <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>ESC</kbd> seem to work. I wanted to boot from live CD and run GParted to resize the partition.

Comment: Have you tried the Delete key?

Comment: Thanks but that did not work either.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the help. The solution that worked was to:

1. Increase the size of the existing virtual disk in VMWare (having shut down Ubuntu).
2. Use GParted to create an extended partition from the unallocated space.
3. Create a logical partition of type ext4 within the extended partition wrapper.
4. Manually mount this new partition. (mount not available in GParted for some reason).
5. Verify with baobab that the new space is available to the filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

No, while working on Vmware. you don't need to do all that. You have to just change virtual OS settings by going in right click on Virtual OS ( ubuntu 11.10) and go to settings. you can change ram and HDD size there.

In Vmware as per I indicated go in Hard disk settings. Click to add. Add more GB as per your requirement. That's it..

Comment: Yes. but as I understand it, that only changes the available size. To make it usable, one has to modify the partition. At least I received a message to that effect.

Comment: Ok. So this is adding a second virtual disk rather than expanding the existing one? Do I need to create a new .vmdk for this new one?

Comment: Yes, you need to create new file .

Comment: Apologies if I am not understanding the concept correctly: I now have a second larger virtual disk as you described.  What do I need to do to make it available to the filesystem? Baobab is still reporting the old configuration with 20GB available.

Comment: GParted shows the second disk space as unallocated. (similar as to when I extended the existing disk originally)

Comment: Thanks for the help. The solution that worked was to: 
a. Increase the size of the existing virtual disk in VMWare (having shut down Ubuntu)
b. Use GParted to create an extended partition from the unallocated space.
c. Create a logical partition of type ext4 within the extended partition wrapper.
d. Manually mount this new partition. (mount not available in GParted for some reason).
e. Verify with baobab that the new space is available to the filesystem.

all the best.